# Value of type 'ConversationDataSource' has no member 'message At' - Swift Error

Tags: ios, swift, chatbot

I'm following an Apple tutorial to make a chatbot and have come across this error which I can't find the solution for:

> Value of type 'ConversationDataSource' has no member 'messageAt'

My code in ConversationViewController.swift

```
 import Foundation
class ConversationDataSource {


    /// message array
    var messages = [openingLine]

    var messageCount: Int {
        return messages.count
    }

    /// Add a new question to the conversation
    func add(question: String) {
        print("Asked to add question: \(question)")

        let message = Message(date: Date(), text: question, type: .question)
        messages.append(message)

    }

    /// Add a new answer to the conversation
    func add(answer: String) {
        print("Asked to add answer: \(answer)")

        let message = Message(date: Date(), text: answer, type: .answer)
        messages.append(message)

    /// The Message at a specific point in the conversation
        func messageAt(index: Int) -> Message {
        print("Asking for message at index \(index)")

        return messages[index]
        }

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add `static` to your messageAt function

Comment: Did you try to perform a `Product -> Clean Build Folder` in Xcode? Are there other compiler errors when you try to build? In particular, could it be that your `ConversationDataSource` class is not compiling because of unrelated syntax issues (i.e. does the whole project actually compile when you simply uncomment the `let message = ...` part?)? Is Xcode autocomplete making any relevant suggestions when you start typing `conversationSource.`?

Comment: @Gamma no other error messages. Cleaning unsuccessful. When uncommenting the let message I get 2 other error messages. Xcode is autocompleting the conversation source.

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha adding static did not work. Made an additional error message ' Static Methods may only be declared on type'

Comment: I don't think a `static` function is what you actually want here, but the error message you got when trying to add one could be and indicator for the issue at hand. To me it sounds like you maybe accidentally declared your `messageAt` function directly in the scope of the `ConversationDataSource.swift` file itself, and not within the scope of your actual `class ConversationDataSource { ... }` declaration.

Comment: That is to say: if `func messageAt(index: Int) -> Message { ... }` is currently located outside the curly brackets that make up the `ConversationDataSource` class, try moving it inside.

Comment: i have attached my entire conversation data source. I tried moving it in the class but got 3 errors. Maybe i did it incorrectly

Comment: Check your curly brackets in that file, they got messed up. `func add(answer: String)`'s closing `}` is missing, and there's an extra `}` at the end of the file.

Comment: @Gamma fixed. However, it doesn't resolve the issue though.

Comment: @MPD can you update the attached code with your fixed version, please?

Comment: Look closely at the scopes of those functions, marked by opening and closing curly brackets. Note where exactly each function begins and ends. Your file currently has a structure like this: 
`C{ f{} f{ f{} }}`. Note that the 3rd function is nested inside the 2nd, and is therefore unaccessible "from the outside". What you want to have instead is a structure like this: `C{ f{} f{} f{} }`.

Comment: Hi there, where is this tutorial? The `messageAt` method is really inside `add` method?